# Run exe hidden or minimized in powershell or cmd

Tags: powershell, cmd

I would like to run .exe hidden or minimized in windows but it doesnt work.

i tried in cmd: `start /min something.exe`

in powershell: `start-process -WindowStyle Hidden something.exe`

it works with something.txt, .log etc

Answer (score 0):

with cmd you can not do this. you can use vbscript instead
1. create a file run.vbs
2. put,

```
Dim sh
Set sh = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
sh.run "cmd /K something.exe & exit", 0 ,false
Set sh = Nothing
```

in run.vbs
3. save and double click to run.

hope this will work..